# DIsplaying members with shortcode

Tags: civimember, custom-fields, display

I've never used civi before so I have no clue what I'm doing, but I need to create a new membership type with categories and display them on a page.  I figured out how to add custom fields, so I used a dropdown with pre-selected categories for that.  So how can I display them on a page with their respective category?

Additionally, I need to create a smart group for each category as well.

I've gotten as far as creating the new membership type and adding the categories via Custom Fields.  There is another page on the site that does what I need, but I can't figure out how the shortcode was configured.

```
[civicrm_contact_directory group="23" search="yes" mainview="78" specialty='custom_8' displaynamefilter=1]
```

I'm guessing the contact_directory group is the membership id???

Any help here would be much appreaciated!

Comment: My guess is that `contact_directory` is a custom thing someone made. If you have command line access to the server you can try to find the code that generates it with `grep -r contact_directory *`